# Division by 2 and infinite loop in C

Tags: c, loops, division

I'm doing an implementation of the 3n+1 algorithm, but for some reason when n=2, the division n = n/2 doesn't change the value, creating an infinite loop, and I can't see why:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void)
{
    int i=0,j=0,n=0,count,max;

        scanf("%d",&i);
        scanf("%d",&j);

        max = 0;

        for(n=i; n<=j; n++){
            count = 0;

            while(n != 1){
                //Debug print
                printf("%d - %d\n",count,n);

                if(n%2 != 0){ //Odd
                    n = 3 * n + 1;
                } else { //Even

                    n = n / 2;

                    //n /= 2;
                    //n = n >> 1;
                }
                count++;
            }
            max = (count > max) ? count : max;
        }
        printf("%d %d %d\n",i,j,max);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

[Solve] The for loop and de while loop was changing the value of n

```
for(k=i; k<j;k++){
    count =0;
    n = k;
    while( n!= 1){
          . . .
```

Comment: I suggest learning how to use a debugger to step through your code and examine the variables.

Comment: It looks like you have disproved the Collatz conjecture....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *is* changing `n`, and is exiting the `while` loop.  However, the code that gets executed after that is responsible for the infinite loop.

If you can't use a debugger, try adding a `printf` statement right after `count = 0` to see what is happening.  Or, assuming that the `while` loop does exit with `n`=1 (which it does), what will happen to `n` when you start another iteration of the `for` loop?

Comment: Also consider the fact the for loop variable will only exit when n>=j, which could be 1000 even if I was 2.

Comment: For example debbuging with i=3 and j=5  the sequence of count, n is      0 - 3,
1 - 10,
2 - 5,
3 - 16,
4 - 8,
5 - 4,
6 - 2,
0 - 2,
0 - 2,
0 - 2, etc... For any reason fail in the case 2/2